# How does a newly installed iOS Google app know about my account the first time I run it?

Tags: ios, single-sign-on

Let's say I have a Google app (e.g. Photos) installed on my iPhone and I have logged into it already.

When I install a second Google app (e.g. Maps) and run it the first time, it already knows about my account and automatically logs me in.

What is the mechanism that Google uses to let the newly installed app to know about all my accounts automatically? What iOS-provided capability, or Google-provided capability allows for this?

Comment: Likely shared keychain

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use the  `identifierForVendor` property on `UIDevice`.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor):

> The value of this property is the same for apps that come from the same vendor running on the same device. A different value is returned for apps on the same device that come from different vendors, and for apps on different devices regardless of vendor.

Comment: I think it's pretty unlikely that Google would log in a user based solely on an app having the same `identifierForVendor` as another Google app.

Comment: @DanielHall I agree. My answer was intended for others trying to create apps with similar functionality, not to reverse-engineer Google's apps.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Google is using keychain groups to share keychain items (stored username and password) between multiple apps from the same developer account. The process is described well here:

http://evgenii.com/blog/sharing-keychain-in-ios/